# VBA Compile Error: "For control variable already in use"

Tags: excel, vba

This particular use of a nested **"For"** is something that I did not expect. I have trimmed it down to a very simple example. The **outer For** loop works perfectly using the member of the Type "abc", but the **enclosed For** statement produces the compiler error. I've hunted for an explanation, but so far have found none.

```
Option Explicit

Private Type abc
    i As Integer
    j As Integer
End Type

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dog As abc
    Dim cat As abc
    
    For dog.i = 1 To 10
        For cat.i = 5 To 9
        
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-control-variable-already-in-use), nested for loops must use different variables for their control counter. And according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/type-statement), Type elements follow the same rules as variables.

> Element names also follow standard variable naming conventions, except that keywords can
> be used.

I suppose there must be something about the struct (`Type`) that when you reference one of its elements, it uses that as a named variable of sorts. So because your two control `abc`s have an element named `i`, the for loop is saying ***"hey, there is already another for loop above me using a control variable named `i`"***. Notice you won't get the same issue if you use `dog.i` for the outer loop, and `cat.j` for the inner.

As for solutions to this, you could store the values of `dog.i` and `cat.i` into a separate variable to use with this loop structure:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dog As abc
    Dim cat As abc
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    
    x = dog.i
    y = cat.i
    
    For x = 1 To 10
        For y = 5 To 9

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had wanted to determine if the error I was seeing was a VBA limitation (flaw) or whether there was some Setting or Option that I did not know, that would be appropriate.
I have come up with a work-around that is acceptable for what I need to do.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Type abc1
    i As Byte
    j As Byte
End Type

Private Type abc2
    i As Byte
    j As Byte
End Type

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dog As abc1
    Dim cat As abc2
    
    For dog.i = 1 To 10
        For cat.i = 5 To 9
        
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```