# For control variable already in use compile error

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop

I am trying to write a nested for loop in visual basic macro which runs on excel.

Here is my simplified code

```
Dim intVar(2) As Integer

For intVar(1) = 0 To 4
    For intVar(2) = intVar(1) To 4
        Var = Var + intVar(1) + intVar(2)
    Next intVar(2)
Next intVar(1)
```

When I try to compile the code "For control variable already in use" compile error is thrown. Is there any solution for using array variables for For Loop or should I declare different variables for each For Loop?

There are some questions with the same tag but none of them for the array type control variables. If you help me I would be glad.

Thank you for your interest

Comment: Use `For i = 0 To 4` and `For j = i To 4` Replace `intVar(1)` with `i` and `intVar(2)` with `j`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65864131) may be useful.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout  Thank you for your kind interest. However, I did not want to declare variables for each For Loop. Instead I tried to do it by an array.

Comment: @sbgib As far as I understand I can not do it by an array too. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't understand your need to use an array for control variables.  In general, it is much better in VBA to use meaningful names.  Using a long text name in VBA does not make code run slower, as code is compiled before running, but makes it much easier to understand code at a time after it is first written.  It is for this reason that I would not use the i,j,k notation for the control variables for loops.

Comment: You cannot do it this way because `intVar` is already used in the first loop.

Comment: @ freeflow I wanted to use an array for control variables because I need to assign values for them frequently. In this example code there is only two nested for loops but in the exact case I need more than 10 nested for loops. I need to obtain a particular nested for loops value (for example sometimes third sometimes fifth etc.) . In order to obtain these values systematically I wantted to use an array as a control variable.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout           Is there any option like pointers in C to use an array?